# How can I make a set of vertices part of an existing plane with an imported image?

Tags: modeling, mesh, image

I imported an image as a plane in order to place vertices marking all the key contours on it. After a while I realized I didn't know how to make those vertices part of the plane they were on.

If I can't move the vertices on the z axis, and have the image move with them, I can't use the image as a reference the way I'd planned and the whole thing becomes much more difficult.

Is there a way to embed those vertices in the plane that has the image? They are already sitting on it. Or maybe a way to import the image again and integrate the vertices with it then?

Answer (score 1):

the only thing that comes to mind is subdividing the plane in edit mode. then moving your new vertices where you want them.

this may become a little more complicated if your image skews while doing this.

let me know if you need clarification. i can post some screen shots.

Comment: Yes, that is what happens - if i move the vertices, the image distorts and then it is no longer useful at a reference. I could simply subdivide it so much that the resulting grid has vertices near all the contours - but it will not be exact, and the image underneath will become hard to see because of all the lines. But i suppose i'll do that, if only to create a rough version that i can then use to make a more exact rendition.

Comment: @kimholder maybe try some place some empties along the plane